# Is there a difference between an one-dimension differential equation and an ordinary differential equation (ODE)?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a difference between an one-dimension differential equation and an ordinary differential equation (ODE)? Or do they mean the same thing?

Also, would anything like $\dot x = x^2+5x-4$ be considered an ODE or one-dimensional differential equation?

Comment: ODE means that there is a single scalar independent variable, traditionally denoted by $t$. Generally the dimension of an ODE refers to the dimension of the space where the *dependent* variable lives. Thus your example is a "one-dimensional ODE".

Answer (score 0):

I think that differential equations need to be at least two-dimensions. In your example, we are solving for the **function** $x$. Also, a two-dimensional differential equation is an ODE.